# Decrease-key/Increase-key support in native libraries

Tags: java, python, heap, guava

I've noticed that most default implementations of heaps in Java (PriorityQueue, Guava MinMaxPriorityQueue, etc) and Python (heapq) don't support the increase-key / decrease-key operations described in [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) for heaps. However, I haven't found an explanation as to why this is so. Does anyone know / is the rationale described somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: There's no great way to put it in your API without either exposing internal details of your heap, or incurring significant overhead in the case where users _don't_ need to modify keys.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the key of a particular element in your heap, your options are essentially:

- To already have a reference to the heap node containing that element.  This means that you have to expose the details of your internal heap representation, constrains your implementation options (you can't use a straight array like the traditional representation), and generally makes your API more difficult to use.
- To maintain a `HashMap` or the like directing each element to its location in the heap.  This incurs significant overhead in the case where users aren't modifying keys.

In addition, Java `Comparator`s expect to be stateless -- comparison operations should always have consistent output for the same inputs -- and modifying keys is rarely used, and rarely strictly necessary, in most algorithms that require the use of a priority queue.